# IOS Facebook SDK 3 upload image with message

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am using the following code to upload an image to Facebook wall :

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logoits.png"];

[FBRequestConnection startForUploadPhoto:img
                       completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Facebook posting %@",result);
    NSLog(@"Facebook posting %@",error);

}];
```

It works as expected but I would like to add a message or title to this uploaded photo, and looking at the documentation of FBRequestConnection there is no example of that. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdk-reference/iossdk/3.0/class/FBRequestConnection/

How do I upload an image with message?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In the Facebook SDK 3.0 only a image can be post using the given methods, and for other actions you need to use graph a pi's.

So for post a image with message you need to use graph-api. Here is the line of codes which lets you to post a image with message on users timeline.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:@"your custom message" forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image) forKey:@"picture"];
_shareToFbBtn.enabled = NO; //for not allowing multiple hits

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) 
 {
     if (error) 
     {
         //showing an alert for failure
         [self alertWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:@"Unable to share the photo please try later."];
     } 
     else
     {
         //showing an alert for success
         [UIUtils alertWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:@"Shared the photo successfully"];
     }
     _shareToFbBtn.enabled = YES;
 }];
```

and also make sure `_shareToFbBtn` is enabled only after login is success.

Comment: if u have an active session and after having posted once and then if you remove publish permission from facebook settings and then try to post it will not give any error but the post will not be added to the users feed.

Comment: thanks a lot, it working fine but if you add link in parameter, like [params setObject:@"http://google.com" forKey:@"link"]; it is not showing me in fb. any idea ?

Comment: @vishy Do you know what all metadata we can upload to facebook while uploading in image? As keys for the parameters dictionary, We can have `@"message"`, `@"picture"` etc. What else? Is there some documentation regarding this?

Comment: @neeraj have a look at the link given at last answer, u need to try for other options..

Comment: Hi vishy, it works perfctly for posting on wall. But if u have any idea of posting on friends wall ?

Comment: @i-bhavik as we are using 'me' for posting on our wall.. try by giving the id of user instead of 'me'

Comment: @i-bhavik have a look at this, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts may help you, and also u may have to add some more permissions i think..

Comment: `Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 2500;
            "fbtrace_id" = "HkQ+T3pxGRU";
            message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}
` got an error

Answer (score 5):

linesvishy's solution works great and it's also worth to note that if you were using Facebook SDK 3.1 and you used method

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForUploadPhoto:_imageToShare];
```

You can just use the following lines to replace it:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:_textToShare forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:_imageToShare forKey:@"picture"];
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Hope it helps! Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for an easy fix in my code. This helped greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that posts and image and a note:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/