# how to Uploading image with text to facebook using FBRequestConnection?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios6

I am trying to upload the text with image using `FBRequestConnection` like as follow but I am only able to upload text,not the image.
But when I am giving any image link in place of img1(image) then I am able to see the image on the facebook wall.

```
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default@2x.png"];

 NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
                               img1, @"picture",
                               @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
                               @"build apps.", @"caption",
                               @"imagae description.", @"description",
                               nil]; 


[params setObject:@"post message" forKey:@"message"];


[FBRequestConnection
 startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
 parameters:params
 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                     id result,
                     NSError *error) {
     NSString *alertText;
     if (error) {
         alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                      @"error: domain = %@, code = %d",
                      error.domain, error.code];
     } else {
         alertText = @"Posted successfully.";
     }
     // Show the result in an alert
     [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result"
                                 message:alertText
                                delegate:self
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                       otherButtonTitles:nil]
      show];
 }];
```

I have taken the two permission **@"publish_actions",@"user_photos"**

Please let me know where I am wrong in this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out my answer in the [IOS Facebook SDK 3 upload image with message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607473/ios-facebook-sdk-3-upload-image-with-message/12615336#12615336)

It is the similar way which you required. Just add some more parameters as per your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Change @"picture" to @"source".
If you are using new Facebook 3.1 SDK you can do it simpler:

```
FBRequest *req = [FBRequest requestForUploadPhoto:img1];
[req.parameters addEntriesFromDictionary:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"post message", @"message", nil]];

FBRequestConnection *con = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
[con addRequest:req completionHandler....
```

Comment: Currently it's required to use "caption" instead of "message"